# window.location.href in iframe does not work in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, scroll, anchor

On the website www.example.org I have an anchor #anchor. I have to work with anchors because that website is written in GWT and it's embedded in an iframe (and both sites have different domains).

Luckily I found a solution to scroll to the anchor which works in Chrome, Safari, IE7, IE8, IE9 but it turns out it does not work in Firefox.

In my code I checked if the browser is one of the IE's. If yes then I do this:

```
window.location = www.example.org#anchor
```

and that works perfectly.

If the browser is not one of those IE's then I do this:

```
window.location.href = '#anchor';
```

and this works perfectly in Chrome and Safari.

However none of both solutions works with Firefox (6). Does anyone  have an idea how I can scroll in FireFox to the anchor?

P.S. scrollIntoView, scrollTo(0,0) and get an element to scroll to that element does not work in this case... After days of trying I figured that only anchors work.

Comment: Have you tried `document.location.href` in FireFox?

Comment: Yes right now. Same result :(

Answer (score 3):

I know this was awhile back but I have just encountered the same issue and disinterred a terrible but effective solution.  The problem: Firefox does not respond to location.hash in some iframes.  The simple example posted above in jsfiddle does work but more complex examples (in my own case in a Facebook app) do not.  The solution: create a visually hidden INPUT element in the location where you want the anchor.

```
<input id="top_anchor" type="text" style="position:relative; z-index:-1; float:left">
```

The CSS is intended to trick the browser into thinking the input is visible but to actually make the element invisible to the user, modify as you see fit for your own case.  The z-index will render it below its parent element (you might need to mess with the parent element to get this to fully work) and the float applied to it will help for the input to collapse in its parent.  It is important that we not use "display:none" or "visibility:hidden" because the browser will consider that element to be visually hidden and the next part won't work.

The next part: in your javascript, rather than changing the hash or location, we find a much more devious way to get the browser to jump to a certain point in the page:

```
document.getElementById('top_anchor').focus();
```

I just tested this in Firefox 8 and it works great.  It's kind of sad that such a disingenuous hack will work but the original, well-intentioned code will not; but I completely understand the thought process that certain behaviors NEED to be triggered by user actions.

Comment: sounds interesting. I have to test it. Thanks for sharing the solution.

Comment: +1 for very gud hack,but it brings bottom of the page.how to bring top of the id section.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(window.location.hash = "anchor",500)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
window.location.hash = "anchor"
```

That should do the trick in every browser. Here a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rk5bZ/) which is working in Firefox. Furthermore the a-anchor has to be visible when the hash is set otherwise FF7 won't jump to the anchor. Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rk5bZ/1/) what won't work in FF7 do demonstrate what you are not allowed to do.

Comment: does not work in FF. (And I'm pretty sure I tried that too for the IE8 browser but the only solution I found was exactly what I posted above)

Comment: It's working. You probably have another problem/bug. Show the code how you tried it.

Comment: Well it works in Chrome and Safari but not in FF. There is not much code I can show which helps. I have only a function which does this: $wnd.location.hash = "anchor"; it's a JSNI function in GWT and in the document I have an anchor like this <a name="anchor"></a>

Comment: I can't tell you why it's failing for you until you put an live example online. But Firefox is supporting it. Take yourself a look at the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location Here you see that window.location has the property .hash and does what it should do.

Comment: it seems to work in FF v3 :D. I use FF7 right now and unfortunately there it also doesn't work

Comment: Could it be that your anchor element is display:none when you are setting the window.location.hash? Because it has to be visible. Otherwise FF7 won't jump to it.

Comment: What do you exactly mean? The anchor is always there since only below the anchor the elements are getting changed dynamically. If it would not have been visible, then it shouldn't also work in chrome wouldn't it?

Comment: I have added an example which won't work in FF7. If it's not your bug then check if you do your complete site/DOM manipulation first and then set the window.location.hash.

Comment: there might be also a problem, that it runs in an iframe (can't change that). But the other browsers can handle that...

Answer (score 0):

Does the element you're scrolling down to have an ID property and is the ID only used once?

Comment: <a name="anchor" id="anchor" ></a> and there is only one of it

Comment: I would try calling it something other than anchor. That might be some kind of reserved word. I never have this problem with FF that you're mentioning.

Comment: wait, is this page you are working on in an iframe of another page?

Comment: yes. and no there is no other way to do it. we must use an iframe :(. (and the anchor is not in the parent window)

Comment: This looks like an iframe problem not a window.location.hash question. Give you iframe an id and name value, say 'bob'. Then do window.bob.src = "http://myurl.com#here".

Comment: if you do window.bob are you accessing the element named bob or the element with id bob? And with myurl.com#here you mean the link of the anchor I guess right? I give it try now

Comment: I just tested it. It does not work either :(. Thanks for patient. I appreciate it a lot!!

Comment: I just found this https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=638598 . I'm not the only fighting with FF and security policy :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for pointing out the window.location.hash instead of
window.location.href.

With window.location.hash I was able to reload the page with the anchor!

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.hash = '#anchor';
window.location.reload(true);">Link text...</a>
```